# Memory leak in migrating to new mongoose collection from existing collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, memory-management, mongoose, node-mongodb-native

I have a multiple unnecessarily large, and poorly unorganized collections in mongodb and I am trying to migrate a subset of that data to a few new collections that have a mongoose schema. However, my approach seems to have a memory leak, as the migration slowly grinds to a halt and the node process eats up all the RAM after a while. Resulting in this error:

`FATAL ERROR: JS Allocation failed - process out of memory`

I start off with a list of the documents I want to migrate over, `people`. Initially, I used a `forEach` over `people`, but that resulted in a very big memory leak with many `cursors` being created before being closed. I then tried using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) to generate each query in series, which is much better than my initial attempt, but there still seems to a slight memory leak, and eventually the error occurs after only a small part of the data has been migrated. What am I missing?

```
var PersonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: String,
  records: [{
    id: String
    date: Date
  }]
});

var Person = mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema);

db = mongoose.connection.db;
// Collections I want to use to use in populating new schema
var members = db.collection('members');
var records = db.collection('records');

// Populate members
members.find().each(function (err, p) {
  if (err) {
    winston.error(err);
  }
  if (p) {
    var id = p['Member ID - Consist'];
    var person = new Patient({
      _id: id,
      records: []
    });

    person.save(function (err) {
      if (err) {
        winston.error(err);
      } else {
        winston.info('Saved %s', id);
      }
    });
  } else {
    winston.info('Done importing members');
  }
});

// Loop through people again and add all their records

Person.find().exec(function (err, people) {
  async.eachSeries(people, function (p, callback) {
    var cursor = records.find({
      'memberId': p.id
    });
    cursor.each(function (err, doc) {
      if (err) {
        throw new Error(err);
      }
      if (doc) {
        p.records.push({
          id: doc['recordId'],
          date: new Date(doc['date'])
        });
      } else {
        p.save(function (err) {
          if (err) {
            winston.error(err);
          } else {
            cursor.close(function () {
              callback();
            });
            winston.info('Data saved for %s', p.id);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }, function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean from MongoDb to Mongoose? Mongoose uses MongoDb.

Comment: So I have a large amount of legacy data in multiple collections and I was hoping to generate a couple new, smaller, and more organized collections with mongoose schemas (so I can use all the nice mongoose functions, e.g. querying, populating, etc.). Is there a better way I should be doing that?

Comment: Is that your actual code? If you're using `eachSeries` then you need to call the `callback` to continue executing with the next item in the series: `callback();` Is the `p` instance a Mongoose Model instance? (You might need to add a bit more code to your question to get help).

Comment: Ah sorry I was simplifying my code in an attempt to make it clearer and missed that part (`callback()` is done after the cursor closing and `p` is a Mongoose Model instance). I updated my code above to hopefully be clearer.